# JRuby require error on .so file

Tags: ruby, serial-port, jruby

I am working on a feature for an application that has to run on JRuby.  Out of habit I develop on 'Native' Ruby.  When I try to run any methods from this class in JRuby I get error messages like:

> MissingSourceFile: no such file to load -- serialport

I think the problem lies in in the require 'serialport.so'.  Is there a way to make this work in JRuby?  Is there another way to require a .so file?  Or a gem that can work with JRuby to provide the SerialPort class?  I tried installing the ruby-serialport gem but that doesn't seem to install properly (Windows nmake issues).

Here is what my class file looks like:

```
require 'serialport.so'
class AlphaDisplay

  #STATES
  SOLID = "b"
  ROTATE = "a"
  BLINK = "c"
  #COLORS
  RED = "1"
  GREEN = "2"
  YELLOW = "3"
  ORANGE = "7"

  def self.message(address = 00, text = "ICS", color = AlphaDisplay::GREEN, state = AlphaDisplay::SOLID)
    address = address.to_s
    if address.length == 1
      address = "0#{address}"
    end
    string = 1.chr + 90.chr + address + 2.chr + 65.chr + 65.chr + 27.chr + 26.chr + state + 28.chr + color + text + 4.chr
    return string
  end
  def self.test(address = 00, text = "ICS", color = AlphaDisplay::GREEN, state = AlphaDisplay::SOLID)
    sp = SerialPort.new(0, 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)
    sp.write(message(address,text,color,state))
    sp.close
  end   
end

def SerialPort::new(port, *params)
  sp = create(port)
  begin
    sp.set_modem_params(*params)
  rescue
    sp.close
    raise
  end
  return sp
end

def SerialPort::open(port, *params)
  sp = create(port)
  begin
    sp.set_modem_params(*params)
    if (block_given?)
      yield sp
      sp.close
      return nil
    end
  rescue
    sp.close
    raise
  end
  return sp
end
```

Comment: You can't use the native Java methods for accessing the serial port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, JRuby doesn't provide any native emulation layer, just the Ruby interpreter in Java.  The problem is that ".so" files are UNIX specific and cannot run on Windows without some sort of emulation/translation.

You're better off avoiding Ruby libraries which require native extensions if you're going to use JRuby.